# Rewarding bounty after bounty finished when question posted before end of bounty?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, bounty

I had a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169975/get-id-for-each-single-v-to-points-point-in-grass) for bounty and got last minute an [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/178655/53268). Now I finally found the time to prove this answer but can't anymore reward the correct answer?!

Should be this time after the finish of the bounty longer for accept the right answer?

Comment: I've set [meta-tag:status-deferred] because this can only be implemented at the SE network level i.e. deferred to the SE network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing an enhancement request like this is something that could only be done at the Stack Exchange network level i.e. via [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) rather than here at Meta GIS Stack Exchange.

I could not find a similar request there when I looked just now but if you decide to post there then, before doing that, be sure to review [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)